# ClickOnce manifest file - duplicate "file" entries being generated

Tags: c#, com, clickonce, manifest

I've had all sorts of [fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437348/deploying-com-components-with-clickonce-application) and [games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441785/duplicate-lines-being-generated-in-manifest-file) with my ClickOnce application, and despite working my way around those problems, I've fallen at the final hurdle.

I need to my WPF (.Net 4.0) app include a COM component and 3 DLL's in my project. The COM component is:

[image]

and the 3 DLLs, which need to be in the executable directory:

[image]

The COM component also needs a custom `.manifest` file, which my project is set to use: here's a sample section from it, referencing one of those DLLs:

```
  <file name="BytescoutVideoMixerFilter.dll" asmv2:size="203368" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<hash xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <dsig:Transforms>
    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
  </dsig:Transforms>
  <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
  <dsig:DigestValue>JYpOccueoR7YDchdz+iCMPquHtg=</dsig:DigestValue>
</hash>
<comClass clsid="{4407F28D-97C2-41C5-A23F-2FAE465CE7BB}" threadingModel="Both" tlbid="{8EDAD3BB-AE5F-43B4-A2F1-B04F4130F2E0}" description="Bytescout Video Mixer Filter" />
```

The full manifest file is [here](http://pastebin.com/YB2rnN0L).

Now the application runs fine locally, both from Visual Studio and running the .exe. However, I need to deploy the app via ClickOnce, including those 3 DLLs.

The only way I can get the DLLs included in the publisher package is to set the build action to "Content". However, if I do this, the published manifest has a duplicate section for each file added: as an example, I set `BytescoutVideoMixerFilter.dll`'s Build Action to **Content**, and  the above manifest snippet becomes:

```
  <file name="BytescoutVideoMixerFilter.dll" asmv2:size="203368" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <hash xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>JYpOccueoR7YDchdz+iCMPquHtg=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
    <comClass clsid="{4407F28D-97C2-41C5-A23F-2FAE465CE7BB}" threadingModel="Both" tlbid="{8EDAD3BB-AE5F-43B4-A2F1-B04F4130F2E0}" description="Bytescout Video Mixer Filter" />
  </file>
  <file name="BytescoutVideoMixerFilter.dll" size="203368">
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>JYpOccueoR7YDchdz+iCMPquHtg=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </file>
```

... so two sections for the one file; the first one is the settings from my manifest, and the other seemingly auto-generated without the `comClass` line. And of course, as both are referencing the same DLL, Windows complains and refuses to run the application.

So I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place:

- If I set the DLL Build Actions to Resource (or anything else), they aren't included in the published package. As the published `.manifest` file references those files, the ClickOnce package won't deploy - it complains about "missing files" (e.g. `BytescoutVideoMixerFilter.dll.deploy`).
- If I set the DLL Build Actions to Content, they're included in the published package - but the published manifest now has duplicate entries.

If I can solve either of those issues, I'm done, and I'm never touching COM again. However, I've tried everything: I cannot get the files included in the published package without also breaking the manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to hack a sort-of workaround. It's horrible, but I:

- Changed the Build Action of the DLLs in the project to "None"
- Created a folder called "Resources" in the project, and put separate copies of the DLL in there. The Build Action on those is "Content".
- Publishing the project now includes those DLLs in the Resources folder, with `.deploy` extensions
- I copy those `.deploy` files to the parent directory
- I can now download/update the application via ClickOnce

I've knocked together a script to copy the files into the right place. It's a pain, and certainly not something I'd have to expect to do - but it works!

Comment: I had a similar situation.  Manifests for referenced packages seem to cause issues with ClickOnce.  For me, it was when using the ArcGIS Runtime dlls.  To help with this issue, I have used Build Events (post build) for executing command line scripts in C# ClickOnce applications.  In case it helps anyone, right-click on your project in Solution Explorer and select Properties.  Then, choose the Build Events tab.